# Understanding Proof of Expected Value Property

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, expected-value

It is stated here that:

[image]

Where $F(x)$ is the CDF. The proof of this is as follows:

[image]

I know that we have to make the right-hand side look like the definition of the expected value, $\int^b_0(xf(x))dx$. I just don't really understand the proof. I don't get the first line at all! Why do we split it up? What is $xd$? If someone could walk me through this proof, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so - ${F(x)}$ being the CDF of ${f(x)}$ means
$$
F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt
$$
now, consider the integral,
$$
\int_0^b[1-F(x)]dx
$$
we start with integration by parts. Using ${u = 1-F(x)}$ and ${dv = dx}$, we get
$$
\int_0^b[1-F(x)]dx = \left.x(1-F(x))\right|_{x=0}^{x=b} - \int_0^b-x\frac{dF}{dx}dx
$$
what is ${\frac{dF}{dx}}$? Well - by the Fundamental theorem of Calculus,
$$
\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)dt = f(x)
$$
so overall we get
$$
\left.x(1-F(x))\right|_{x=0}^{x=b} - \int_0^b-xf(x)dx = \left.x(1-F(x))\right|_{x=0}^{x=b} + \int_0^bxf(x)dx
$$
now - note that
$$
\left.x(1-F(x))\right|_{x=0}^{x=b} = b(1-F(b)) - 0(1-F(0))
$$
of course the right-most term is just $0$. ${F(b)=1}$. Why? Well,
$$
F(b) = \int_0^bf(x)dx = 1
$$
because ${f(x)}$ is a random variable. That means ${b(1-F(b))}$ is ${b(1-1) = 0}$. And so there we have it,
$$
\int_0^b[1-F(x)]dx = \left.x(1-F(x))\right|_{x=0}^{x=b} + \int_0^bxf(x)dx = \int_0^bxf(x)dx = E(x)
$$